# Trigger admin controller custom action on button click

Tags: javascript, backend, ajax

I have 2 buttons for my form, currently the main save button works like:

```
$this->_updateButton('save', 'onclick', 'submitForm()');
```

and some JS so it shows the "Please Wait" javascript loader:

```
function submitForm() {
    $('edit_form').request({
         onComplete: function()  { 
             window.location.href = document.URL; 
         }
     })  
}
```

This works well because it's just posting the form. I need to add another button to post the same form but call a different action other than `saveAction`, I am currently doing:

```
$postBackUrl = $this->getUrl('*/mymodule/custom');
$this->_addButton('sync', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('My Action'),
    'onclick'   => "submitSyncForm('$postBackUrl')",
    'class'     => 'save'
),3,5);
```

I then have this Javascript to post the form:

```
function submitSyncForm(url){
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method:'post',
        onComplete: function()  { 
            window.location.href = document.URL; 
        }
    });
}
```

The form shows the Please Wait and posts to `customAction` correctly but the post values are empty when I try to access them via `$this->request->getPost()`.

Could someone point me in the right direction on posting the form to a custom action other than `saveAction` please?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, played around and came up with this solution. If I change my form action in the JS and call the `form.Request()` it posts the correct values back:

```
function submitSyncForm(url){
    $('edit_form').writeAttribute('action', url);
    $('edit_form').request({
         onComplete: function()  { 
             window.location.href = document.URL; 
         }
     }) 
}
```

I'm not sure this is the advised method but it seems to work nicely.